# How can I round to whole numbers in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, rounding

I have the following code to calculate a certain percentage:

```
var x = 6.5;
var total;

total = x/15*100;

// Result  43.3333333333
```

What I want to have as a result is the exact number `43` and if the total is `43.5` it should be rounded to `44`

Is there way to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Use the [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round) function to round the result to the nearest integer.

Comment: The credit for the link goes to @Jeremy. Thanks for inserting it -- it made starting out on SO a lot more fun to have the fifth answer I ever wrote get as many votes as this one did, which was surely due to the link. :-)

Comment: Didn't OP want to round UP? If so maybe [Math.ceil()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) would be more appropriate

Comment: @martellalex: From the question, the OP wanted 43.333 to round to 43 but 43.5 to round to 44, which exactly matches ECMAScript's Math.round()'s behavior of rounding to nearest, _and_ running exact half-integers towards positive infinity.

Answer (score 72):

```
//method 1
Math.ceil(); // rounds up
Math.floor(); // rounds down
Math.round(); // does method 2 in 1 call

//method 2
var number = 1.5; //float
var a = parseInt(number); // to int
number -= a; // get numbers on right of decimal

if(number < 0.5) // if less than round down
    round_down();
else // round up if more than
    round_up();
```

either one or a combination will solve your question

Answer (score 13):

```
total = Math.round(total);
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 9):

Use `Math.round` to round the number to the nearest integer:

```
total = Math.round(x/15*100);
```

Answer (score 7):

a very succinct solution for rounding a float x:

`x = 0|x+0.5`

or if you just want to floor your float

`x = 0|x`

this is a bitwise or with int 0, which drops all the values after the decimal