# javascript - how to round to nearest integer

Tags: javascript, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I round of to whole numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968042/how-can-i-round-of-to-whole-numbers-in-javascript)

In javascript is there a function which allows me to round to the nearest integer? Either up or down.

So:

**2.1 = 2

2.9 = 3

4.5 = 5

1.1 = 1**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [`Math.round(number)`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_round.asp):

```
var i = Math.round(2.1);
```

Answer (score 5):

`Math.round(x)` and `Math.floor(x)`

both documented [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp)

Answer (score 1):

use Math.round()

EDIT:

Mine was wrong the one above me is correct

Comment: I was thinking of C and not javascript