# How to round a float number?

Tags: javascript

Is there some useful function in JavaScript that could help to round any float number to the closest neighbour either whole number or a float number with .5 ?

```
Input -> Output: 

 - > 2.1 -> 2.0

   > 2.4 -> 2.5

   > 1.9 -> 2

....
```

Comment: Multiply by 2, round, divide by 2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript - how to round to nearest integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172835/javascript-how-to-round-to-nearest-integer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below functions:

```
var intvalue = Math.floor( floatvalue );
var intvalue = Math.ceil( floatvalue ); 
var intvalue = Math.round( floatvalue );

// `Math.trunc` was added in ECMAScript 6
var intvalue = Math.trunc( floatvalue );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function my_round(x){
  return Math.floor(x) + Math.round((x - Math.floor(x)) * 2) / 2 
}
```

Or better, use the method suggested by @ritaj

```
function myRound(x){
  return Math.round(x * 2)/2 
}
```

Comment: `myRound(x)` instead

Comment: why though, what's the problem with my_round

Comment: There is no problem, it's just that everyone that uses JavaScript uses camelCase instead of snake_case.

Answer (score 0):

### Not the shortest but work

```js
function roundNumberWith05 (num){
  const diff = num - Math.floor(num);
  if (diff < 0.25 || diff > 0.75) {
    return Math.round(num * 2) / 2;
  } else {
    return num - diff + 0.5;
  }
}
console.log('2.1 --', roundNumberWith05(2.1));
console.log('2.4 --', roundNumberWith05(2.4));
console.log('1.9 --', roundNumberWith05(1.9)); 
console.log('1.75 --', roundNumberWith05(1.75)); 
console.log('1.74 --', roundNumberWith05(1.74)); 
console.log('1.76 --', roundNumberWith05(1.76)); 
console.log('2.688 --', roundNumberWith05(2.688)); 
console.log('2.2588 --', roundNumberWith05(2.2488));
```