# how to deal with this round off error

Tags: javascript

When I did some simple arithmetic in Javascript, there was some thing kind of round off error. I don't want this, but I don't know how to deal with it.
This is the example:

38.8 * 3 => 116.39999999999999

[image]

Comment: You'll need to round the number to the nearest whole number. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968042/how-can-i-round-to-whole-numbers-in-javascript

Comment: You can round off number like this - var n = num.toFixed(2);

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
function multiply (a, b) {
   exp = b.toString().length - 2;
   function makeInt (num) {
       return num * Math.pow(10, exp);
   }
   function makeFloat(num) {
       return num / Math.pow(100, exp);
   }
   return makeFloat(makeInt(a) * makeInt(b));
} 

var result = multiply(38.8,3)

console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v51s34st/

Answer (score 0):

use Math.ceil(38.8*3) or Math.floor(38.8*3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`parseFloat((38.8*3).toFixed(2))`