# Numbro v1 format for round numbers

Tags: javascript

I'm not able to find the exact format to round numbers (no digits after the decimal) in Numbro with the old format (v1).
Found a Github [issue](https://github.com/BenjaminVanRyseghem/numbro/issues/437) that looks like it's the same question, but haven't been able to find any other resource.
Using the [try me](https://numbrojs.com/old-try-me.html) from Numbro, I would want 12345.67 to be formatted as 12346 (rounding to 0 digits after the decimal). `0.0`, `0.`, `0[.]` and similar variants don't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I round to whole numbers in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968042/how-can-i-round-to-whole-numbers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Math.round()`:

```js
console.log('Math.round(35.5) =>', Math.round(35.5));
```

Answer (score -1):

use parseInt()
it will parse all value to integer

```
parseInt("11.38");

output - 11
```

reference https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: This won't round correctly. Parseint(12345.67) will return 12345 when the Op wants it rounded to 12346.